# Encrypting unicode strings with pyaes

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes

The following code works well:

```
import os, pyaes
key = os.urandom (16)
aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR (key)
encrypted = aes.encrypt ('Hello world')
aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR (key)
decrypted = aes.decrypt (encrypted)
print (encrypted)
print (decrypted)
```

But when I try to encode a unicode string, like a string containing hebrew letters for example, it raises an error:

```
ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

How can I encode unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode can be more than one byte wide, however your AES encoder/decoder expects a string of single bytes.

You need to encode your unicode into single bytes (typically utf8 works for this):

```
unicode_string = u"\u00b0C"
encrypted = aes.encrypt(unicode_string.encode("utf8"))
```

then when you decrypt it you need to decode it:

```
decrypted = aes.decrypt(encrypted).decode("utf8")
```